# convert javascript regex to posix regix

Tags: javascript, c, regex

javascript regex:

```js
reg = /\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\//
```

I use it to remove code comments like "/* xxxx */", which work fine.

Now I want to convert to posix extended regex use c language,

```c
// use regex.h
// regcomp
const char *patten = "TODO";  // need convert from javascript regex
regcomp(&re, patten,REG_EXTENDED);
```

I try as follow:

```c
const char *patten = "\\/\\*[[:space:]^[:space:]]*?\\*\\/";
/*
* javascript regex white space \s convert to posix [:space:]
*/
```

but it not work.  where is wrong?

Comment: I"m more familiar with CLI uses of POSIX regex but I don't think you can do non-greedy matching in POSIX regex, if i recall correctly.

Comment: Also, I don't think your space/nonspace character class set will work. Perhaps this instead `([[:space:]]|[^[:space:]])`. But would `.` work as instead?

Comment: @xdhmoore  javascript regex [\s\S]  replace by ".",   lazy ? will not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it as

```c
const char *patten = "/\\*[^*]*\\*+([^/*][^*]*\\*+)*/";
```

*Details*:

- `/\*` - starting `/*` char sequence
- `[^*]*` - zero or more characters other than `*`
- `\*+` - one or more literal `*`
- `([^/*][^*]*\*+)*` - zero or more sequences of:

  - `[^/*]` - a char other than a `/` and `*`
  - `[^*]*` - zero or more chars other than asterisk
  - `\*+` - one or more asterisks
- `/` - a closing `/` char.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9kKH7A/1).